# Google cloud: CDN (https) gives static up to 20 seconds

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using Google cloud.

In the logs of the load balancer, it can be seen that the CDN (https) gives static from 2 to 20 seconds. This happens often, provided that a couple of people use the site.

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17v4s.jpg)
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4WRj.jpg)

Also, the problem is not only with him, but also with Cloud Run. Sometimes it gives the static for 2 seconds. It is difficult, but really to try to find an explanation. But in the situation with the CDN I cannot find an explanation.

europe1
Belgium

details on the situation in the second image:

1. what's being cached: images (sizes on screenshots 1,2)
2. frontend: a load balancer with cloud cdn enabled
3. backend: a storage bucket ([config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmd5c.png))

response times are beyond unreasonable

Detailed settings:
Cache mode: Use origin headers (to preserve original max-age attributes of images)
Restricted content: Public access to the content cached by Cloud CDN allowed
Negative caching: Disabled
Serve while stale: Disabled

Frontend: https, managed certificate, premium network tier

Comment: What does this mean: "gives static"?

Comment: Provide details on what is being cached and from where. Provide details on how the CDN and load balancer are configured.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The server responds slowly to requests, including the CDN responding slowly to requests related to static content.

Comment: @JohnHanley etails on the situation in the second image:

1. what's being cached: images

2. frontend: a load balancer with cloud cdn enabled

3. backend: a storage bucket.

response times are beyond unreasonable.

Detailed settings:
Cache mode: Use origin headers (to preserve original max-age attributes of images).
Restricted content: Public access to the content cached by Cloud CDN allowed.
Negative caching: Disabled.
Serve while stale: Disabled.

Frontend: https, managed certificate, premium network tier

Comment: Saying **images** is not a detail. Specify the image size, location, etc. Edit your question and not post details as a comment.

Comment: @JohnHanley, okay. I added sizes and screenshot of configuration storage bucket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check high latency in a network, you have to check each path segment which may cause high latency and there are different metrics to measure it.

High latency in network can be introduced:

1. Between the original client and the load balancer - You can see the
   latency   of that segment with the metric https/frontend_tcp_rtt.
2. Between the load balancer and the backend instance- Which can be
   reviewed   with the metric https/backend_latencies (this metric also
   includes the app   processing time in your backend).
3. By the software running on the instance itself- To investigate this
   check   the access/error logs on the backend instance software and
   resource   utilization of the VM instance.

For detailed information about metrics, check [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-loadbalancing).

Also confirm that latency which you are observing is [httpRequest.latency](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#httprequest) or not, because it measures the entire duration of time it takes from when a request is made by the user to the time it takes for the response to get back to that user.

You can optimize latency for your [application by using the external HTTP(S) load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tutorials/optimize-app-latency#optimizing).